# Display pandas Dataframe in PHP browser

Tags: php, python, pandas, shell-exec

I have two files namely, `python1.py` and `python1.php`. I have created a pandas dataframe and want to display the result in php browser. However, I am not getting the result. Content of the files are:

python1.py

```
import pandas as pd 

data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])
print df
```

python1.php

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python python1.py');
$output = shell_exec($command );
echo $output;
```

I have kept the two files in `C:\wamp\www\`. Another point is that if there are multiple outputs, then the outputs are coming in a single line in PHP browser.

Comment: Try providing the absolute path of python interpreter. Eg. `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I tried but failed to get output

Comment: Just now I tried, but nothing is coming.

Comment: Try this. `<?php
    
    passthru('/usr/bin/python /path/to/python1.py');
    $buffer=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $buffer;
    
    ?>`

Comment: Sorry, It is not working.

Comment: Change the command to `which python` and see if it returns anything.

Comment: You meant the version of python? If it is then: Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score -1):

Try putting df in brackets:

```
print (df)
```

Your code worked in my WAMP server(PHP code) once I have put df in brackets.

(Of course, provided that everything else in your server is configured for python)